# C++ segmentation fault when calling function from a new location

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am having an issue where I get a segmentation fault when calling the same function with the same parameters from a different location. I was trying to program something else in that function, and had no idea why I was getting a seg fault. Then I narrowed it down to the writeSector function, so I removed everything else and tried to figure out why that was giving me a seg fault and I still have no idea why. Example below of calling the same function, and then calling it from within another function:

```
test[0] = '0';
test[1] = '0';
test[2] = '1';
test[3] = '0';
test[4] = '0';
test[5] = '4';
test[6] = '0';
test[7] = '0';
test[8] = '5';
test[9] = '0';
test[10] = '0';
test[11] = '5';
test[12] = '0';
test[13] = '0';
test[14] = '6';
test[15] = '9';
test[16] = '9';
test[17] = '9';
disk->writeSector(0, test);
disk->writeSector(10, test);
disk->writeSector(10, test);
disk->writeSector(10, test);
disk->writeSector(10, test);
generateRootDir(10); //Seg fault here.
```

The function literally calls the same code as shown below:

```
void FileSystem::generateRootDir(int rootBlock)
{
    disk->writeSector(10, test);
}
```

The writeSector function is shown below.

```
void BlockDisk::writeSector(int address, char* block)
{
    if (address > blocks || address < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "[writeSector] ERROR: Sector " << address << " out  of bounds!" << std::endl;
    }
    std::fstream diskWrite;
    diskWrite.open(disk, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::out);
    if (diskWrite)
    {
        diskWrite.seekp(address*BLOCKSIZE, diskWrite.beg);  
        diskWrite.write(block, BLOCKSIZE);
        diskWrite.close();
    } else {
        printf("Error opening file to write\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

I then tried to set a break point a line above the generateRootDir function call. This was the given output, everything looks OK to me and I don't see why anything here would cause a segmentation fault.

```
Breakpoint 1, FileSystem::mount (this=0x55555576bc20) at FileSystem.cpp:55
55          disk->writeSector(10, test);
(gdb) s
BlockDisk::writeSector (this=0x55555576c0c0, address=10,
    block=0x55555576bc90 "001004005005006999") at BlockDisk.cpp:21
21          if (address > blocks || address < 0)
(gdb) s
25          std::fstream diskWrite;
```

And then the rest of the writeSector function goes well. Then calling generateRootDir:

```
FileSystem::mount (this=0x55555576bc20) at FileSystem.cpp:56
56          generateRootDir(10);
(gdb) s
FileSystem::generateRootDir (this=0x55555576bc20, rootBlock=10)
    at FileSystem.cpp:147
147         disk->writeSector(10, test);
(gdb) s
BlockDisk::writeSector (this=0x0, address=10,
    block=0x55555576bc90 "001004005005006999") at BlockDisk.cpp:21
21          if (address > blocks || address < 0)
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555556733 in BlockDisk::writeSector (this=0x0, address=10,
    block=0x55555576bc90 "001004005005006999") at BlockDisk.cpp:21
21          if (address > blocks || address < 0)
(gdb) s
```

The gdb seems the same for both calls yet one gives a segmentation fault. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: `writeSector (this=0x0,` -- Look at the value of `this`.  Does that look right to you, i.e. a bogus object?  That's why you should post a [mcve], so that we know where your variables are coming from and how they're created, variables like `disk`.

Comment: Try running your code through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).  If you're stepping on memory you shouldn't be, it will tell you.

Comment: *I don't see why anything here would cause a segmentation fault.* -- Accessing a null pointer as if it is a valid object could do that, and from the output you're showing, that is what it looks like.

Comment: `disk` is null. We can't tell you why without more code. [mcve], please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this line succeeds:

```
disk->writeSector(10, test);
```

And the identical line inside `generateRootDir` fails with `disk == NULL`:

```
void FileSystem::generateRootDir(int rootBlock)
{
    disk->writeSector(10, test);
}
```

Then the value of `disk` is valid at the first location, but not valid at the second.

Most likely these two `disk`s refer to different variables (one of which has been properly initialized, and the other one hasn't).

You can verify this theory in GDB: `print &disk` will produce different results inside and outside of `generateRootDir`.

Comment: Yep this was the issue. I was supposed to initialize it in the constructor but for some reason it was redeclared and initialized in the function where the lines worked. I was certain it was all done in the constructor so I wasn't even looking there for an issue.